# cPanel Check Constraint in syntax

Tags: mysql

I am working on the phpmyadmin interface from cPanel (mysql) and I am having trouble adding a check constraint, the column type is char and 1 value max

I tried this

```
ALTER TABLE user_admin;
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PersonAge CHECK type IN ('c','e','a');
```

But it gives me this error:
"Unknown declaration. (near "ADD" at position 0)"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi colon after `ALTER TABLE user_admin >>>> ; <<<<< ADD ....`
It should be:

```
ALTER TABLE user_admin ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_PersonAge CHECK type IN ('c','e','a');
```